# Hide a template part when page is password protected?

Tags: conditional-tags, private

I'd like to hide the sidebar of my page when the page is password protected and the password has not yet been entered.

I've searched for a while and haven't found any condition I could use. Maybe `get_post_status` could help, but still, I wouldn't know when the user has entered the password and can see the full page.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to clarify. *Private* posts are not the same thing as *password-required* posts. Which are you after?

Comment: Sorry, seems that when I wrote the article I was mixing up password required and private. Modified the question to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're after [`post_password_required()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_password_required):

```
<?php if ( ! ( $post->post_password && post_password_required() ) ) get_sidebar() ?>
```

Comment: Or [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) for *private* posts.

Comment: Where does the code go, please?

Comment: Wherever you want to conditionally include the template